# Compute closed form for probability of some event

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, closed-form

Let $(d, m) \in \mathbb{N}^2$, and let $X_1, \dots, X_m$ be drawn identically uniformly and independently over $[d]$. For $(i,j,k) \in [d]^3$ we define the event $S_{ijk}$ in the following way
$$S_{ijk} = \left\{ \sum_{t = 2}^{m} \boldsymbol{1}\left\{ X_{t-1} = i \right\} \cdot \boldsymbol{1}\left\{ X_{t} = j \right\}  = 1 \text{ and } \sum_{t = 2}^{m} \boldsymbol{1}\left\{ X_{t-1} = i \right\} \cdot \boldsymbol{1}\left\{ X_{t} = k \right\}  = 1 \right\}$$
I am interesting in finding a closed form expression for $\mathbf{P}(S_{ijk})$, the probability of that event.

Please correct me if I am wrong, but here are a few elements I gathered so far:

- For $t \in [2 \dots m]$ the $(X_{t-1}, X_t)$ are uniformly distributed over $[d] \times [d]$, although (as @did pointed out) they are not independent.
- The value of $\mathbf{P}(S_{ijk})$ should be independent of $i$.
- It seems reasonable to split into two cases depending on whether $j = k$ or not.

Comment: When $j=k$, you seem to be assuming that the events $$S_{ij}^t = \left\{ X_{t-1} = i,\, X_t = j \right\}$$ are independent, for $(i,j)$ fixed, when $t$ varies. They are not.

Comment: You are right, I mistakenly assumed their independence. Let me fix the question.

Comment: This fundamentally seems like a combinatorics question (This is akin to "How many 10 digit numbers exist that have one "11" and one "12" in it?); if you wanted those sums to equal 0 as opposed to 1, I can see a dynamic programming solution (i.e. a recursive solution (still not closed form)), not sure if that helps though.

Comment: I agree with your comment (although one can argue that when dealing with finite support, many probability problems amount to combinatoric questions). The event I am interested in has the sums equal to one, and I am not so much interested in programmatic solutions rather analytical ones.